# Android: REmove icon from springboard and launch this application from other application

Tags: android

How to remove application icon from springboard but I don't want to uninstall, just remove icon  from springboard and this app will be launched from another application. In a simple word, I want to make another springboard like this and launch application from there not from anywhere else. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the AndroidMainfest.xml of your application, remove the below line for the activity that you do not want to have the launcher.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

and change `android.intent.action.MAIN` action to something that is your app specific

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

For example, one can change it to below to represent custom intent action:

```
<action android:name="com.example.action.MAIN" />
```

Now, you should be able to launch this application from another application using something like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.action.MAIN");
    currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

To remove application from springboard you can try this:

```
  PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context,LauncherActivity.class);
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,     
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Now to start your application from another application you can do the following steps:

1.Create an intent with action=MAIN and category=LAUNCHER

2.Get the PackageManager from the current context using context.getPackageManager

3.packageManager.queryIntentActivity(, 0) where intent has category=LAUNCHER, action=MAIN or packageManager.resolveActivity(, 0) to get the first activity with main/launcher

4.Get the ActivityInfo you're interested in

5.From the ActivityInfo, get the packageName and name

6.Finally, create another intent with with category=LAUNCHER, action=MAIN, componentName = new ComponentName(packageName, name) and setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

7.Finally, context.startActivity(newIntent)